# Approximating e using loops based on user input

Tags: c

I'm working on an assignment in a first year C class and we are in the loop section of a textbook. I've already learned a few languages but I believe I am doing this wrong somehow since I am not getting the correct output. I believe I need to do this question using loops (so no additional math libraries). Normally I'd use a debugger, but I'm programming C using sublime text and the command prompt so I don't think that's possible. We also have not gone through methods/functions/whatever C uses yet, so my solution can't use that stuff.

Using only C89 is preferred.

Here is the question:

> The value of the mathematical constant *e* can be expressed as an
>   infinite series:
>   *e* = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + ... 
>   Write a program that approximates *e* by computing the value of 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + ... + 1/*n*!
>   where *n* is an integer entered by the user.

Note that I believe *!* in this case means factorial.

I'm checking my output against that of this sigma calculator, and just adding 1 to the calculator's output to check if my result is correct or not.

http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/sigma-calculator.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    float e = 1;/* Start off as 1 since the equation adds 1 anyways */
    int input, i, j;

    /* Ask the user for the value that they want to use, and store it in a variable */
    printf("Enter an integer to use to approximate: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    for (i = 1; i < input; i++)
    {
        /* This inside loop is for the factorial, where j goes through all of the factorials for each i */
        for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            e += (1/(float)j);
        }

    }

    printf("e equals %f\n", e);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any factorial implementation in your code

Comment: You can probably use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Comment: "Note that I believe *n* in this case means factorial." No, `!` means factorial, which you're omitting in your code.

Comment: @m0skit0 Added a comment in the for loop showing where the factorial implementation is

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yeah that's what I meant, just wrote the wrong character there. Sorry about that.

Comment: I should probably mention that there's a good chance gdb is already installed.

Comment: @AlexPodworny That's not a factorial implementation. I suggest you revise what [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) is.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes I think my main issue was I didn't understand factorial well enough - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop should be this way:

```
for(i=1; i<=input; i++)
{
    int result = 1;
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
    {
        result = result * j;
    }
    //now the "result" is the factorial of i
    e += 1 / (float)result; // 1/factorial(1) + 1/factorial(2) + ...
}
```

Comment: As per the question details, unfortunately I can't use functions :(

Comment: I tried using your solution and I am still getting incorrect output... when I input 2, my output is "e equals 2.000000", when the correct output (I believe) should be 2.500000.

Comment: The condition in your code was wrong. It should've been `i <= input`. But since you'd declared it that way, I put the same thing.

Comment: Your welcome, also check Akash's answer for a faster solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing the right thing in your factorial calculation. Your are summing when you should be multiplying. Your inner loop should probably look like this :

```
    /* This inside loop is for the factorial, where j goes through all of the factorials for each i */
    float inverse_factorial_i = 1;
    for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
    {
        inverse_factorial_i *= (1/(float)j);
    }
```

And then

`e += inverse_factorial_i`

Comment: Thanks for your help, yours and farukdgn's answers helped me the most, but I can only accept one answer, sorry! Take an upvote though :)

Answer (score 2):

The loop can be simple enough like this :

```
int fact = 1 ;
for(int i = 1; i < input; ++i)
{
    fact *= i ;
    e += (1.0f/(float)fact);
}
```

No nested loop is required.
[Here](http://ideone.com/Puafh7) is a working version.

Comment: `i < input` or `i <= input` ?

Comment: Yes that should be `<=` but O.P. posted condition as `<` so maybe O.P. wants to loop `n-1` times.

Answer (score 1):

No your code just makes sums over i of sums over j in [1,i] of 1/j.
So you calculates 1/1 + (1/1+1/2) + (1/1+1/2+1/3) + ... and not 1/1 + (1/1*1/2) + (1/1*1/2*1/3) + ...

That should be something like:

```
for (i = 1; i < input; i++)
{
    float inversefact = 1;
    for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
    {
        inversefact *= (1/(float)j);
    }
    e += inversefact;

}
```